# Is a data processing operation the main contributor to high CPU usage?

Tags: .net, multithreading, cpu, profiler

I'm really new to profiling .NET applications. My goal is to determine which codes contributes to the high CPU usages. There's an observation that I've just made which I want to be verified.

Given the first screenshot, I highlighted the timeline where cpu usage of thread pool ID 14876 is high and I got the top methods on the upper right pane. I noticed that the highest time consuming method is an I/O operation while the second one is data processing operation. My hunch says that only data processing operations contribute to high CPU usages because I/O operations mostly just waits until an I/O response is received.

[image]

Thus, given the second screenshot where there is nearly zero CPU usage in that same thread, it shows a much higher time consumption of 1736ms when executing an I/O operation. So is it correct for me to conclude that only data processing operations contribute to high CPU usage?

[image]

Comment: I think the correct thing to conclude is that this profiler is giving you very misleading information.  Read() is the only method executing.  But it isn't using CPU at all, no doubt waiting for the Read() to complete.   Lots of inefficiencies are visible in the profile data, like blocking on I/O in a threadpool thread, using Control.Invoke() instead of BeginInvoke() and firehosing the UI thread with too many invokes, but without any visible code it is just guessing.

Comment: @HansPassant you mentioned that the Read() isn't using CPU at all, no doubt waiting for the function to complete, do you mean that it is true then that blocking I/O does not contribute to high CPU usage?

Comment: That's what "blocking" means.  If code blocks then it isn't executing and not using CPU.

Comment: Then that answers my question. It's true that I have many invokes to the UI thread. Regarding the blocking on I/O in a threadpool thread inefficiency, do you mean that it should have been an asynchronous I/O operation?

Comment: 1) Are you doing sampling, or instrumenting? It looks to me like you're doing instrumenting. (Sampling is blind to I/O.) 2) Don't look at self time; look at inclusive time. 3) Don't look at milliseconds. Look at percents. You don't know if milliseconds are a lot or a little unless you divide them by the total.

Comment: I did timeline profiling using dotTrace. I do not know what's instrumenting though.